# Elegant way to check if .Net object is empty

Tags: c#

I have an `X509Certificate2` property, and I want to check in the set section, if the value that was set is empty.
When I try to access to any `X509Certificate2` property such as publickey, I got this exception:
`System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException` occurred in `mscorlib.dll`.

sure, I can write something such this example:

```
private static X509Certificate2 _certificate;

    public X509Certificate2 Certificate
    {
        get
        {
            return _certificate;
        }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                if (value.PublicKey != null)
                    _certificate = value;
            }
            catch(CryptographicException)
            {
                _certificate = null;
            }

        }
    }
```

but I want a nicer way, does any one have an idea?

Comment: this is nothing that can be done universally for *every* object. It depends on the underlying type

Comment: Are you sure that `value` is not null?

Comment: @Groo If `value` were null, I bet he would get a `NullReferenceException` instead of a `CryptographicException` when trying to access `value.PublicKey`

Comment: Don't hide the exception, that just causes a hard to diagnose other exception later, like NullReferenceException.  The certificate is bad, don't let that go unnoticed.

Comment: to check if value is null, I can write simply if(value == null), but I look for way to check if the value is empty.  if there is a way to check it for every object - it is the best. if not, do you have a way to check it in this case (of X509Certificate2 object)

Comment: @yas4891: I agree, I missed the first part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN said "The key value is not an RSA or DSA key, or the key is unreadable." So maybe yours  algorithm is not RSA or DSA. Check what returns GetKeyAlgorithm()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple option - access the Handle property:

```
public X509Certificate2 Cretificate
{
   get { return _certificate; }
   set { _certificate = value.Handle == IntPtr.Zero ? null : value}
}
```

as I know, otherwise when you define:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();
```

and will try to set your certificate with the empty cert - you might get an exception.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
public X509Certificate2 Certificate     
{
     get { return _certificate; }
     set { _certificate = value.PublicKey ?? null; }
}
```

Basically:

> _certificate = value.PublicKey is it isn't null, else it equals null.

But now writing this, I think that will not work, so might need to use a [ternary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.80%29.aspx):

```
public X509Certificate2 Certificate     
{
     get { return _certificate; }
     set { _certificate = value == null ? null : value.PublicKey; }
}
```

Which means:

> _certificates = null if value is null, else it equals value.PublicKey

I think this is the right approach since your value being null will cause the Exception.

Comment: if - as OP states - the call to value.PublicKey throws an exception, this will not improve things

Comment: I don't think you understand the problem. The `PublicKey` property will throw a `CryptographicException` in its `getter` if it is in an invalid state.  That's his issue.